# li:first-of-type selecting everything

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style only the first li element. When I wrap a li element with an a element everything is selected. Here's my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <a href="#"><li class="box one"></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="box two"></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="box three"></li></a>
</ul>
```

and CSS:

```
li:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.one {
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

.two {
    background-color: crimson;
}

.three {
    background-color: darkorange;
}
```

Any explanation as to why this is happening is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your `li` elements are surrounded by anchor tags. Since there's only one `li` inside each `a`, the `li` is always the first of type. Also worth pointing out is the fact that `ul` elements (also `ol`) can only wrap `li` elements, nothing else, ever, lest your HTML be invalid.

Try this instead:

```
<ul>
  <li class="box one"><a href="#">asd</a></li>
  <li class="box two"><a href="#">asdf</a></li>
  <li class="box three"><a href="#">asfd</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can also mention, that direct children of  `ul` element can only be `li` elements, otherwise it is invalid html.

Comment: I will mention that, thanks for the suggestion, @suslov.